# The path-independence of work done by an electrostatic field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, work, coulombs-law, conservative-field

We know that work done by conservative forces is path-independent and so is work done by electrostatic force but how can we prove it using Coulomb's law?

I know such a question has already been asked but I want an explanation as a high schooler a I am still not aware of stokes law and surface integrals.

Comment: Calculate the line integral directly and show that for a general path it is only dependant on its end points.  Or assume its Conservative E=-grad(v) and solve for V thus proving it is conservative

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding intgrals here is possible, but then you do need a derivative, or in fact a "gradient" in order to write the electric field as the gradient of a potential.

But I think that the gradient concept, when explained in terms of uphill and downhill, are within high-school limits, or even elementary school. So if you then just explain the fact that in a hilly landscape the height you gain or loose is independent of the path but only depends on your location in the beginning and in the end, then you have in fact proven that
$$ {\bf E} = -\nabla V $$
is a conservative force.

And the fact that $ {\bf E} $ can be written like that, is obtainable from from Coulomb's law for the case of a single point charge, although you do of course have to follow the math that creates the $1/r^2$ force from $V=1/r$. You can then say that every situation consists of a large amount of point charges, in order to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

You might start off with a diagram to showing electric field lines and equipotential lines around a positive point charge.

[image]

You explain that work is done when moving along a field line (force and displacement parallel to one another) and no work is done moving along an equipotential line (force and displacement perpendicular to one another).

Then discuss paths **abcdef** and **aghijf**.

Finally, in general, any path from **a** to **f** can be made up of the sum of infinitesimal steps along filed lines and equipotential lines.